# Using For loop Int in DataGridView.Rows[]

Tags: c#, .net, for-loop

In my WFA project (C#) i need to read all DataGridView values to arrays.I want to use for loop.
For example, for first row i have tried to use i = 0 value and tried to read values to arrays.
Like;

```
string[] Array1 = new string[2];    
for (int i = 0; i < NumOfRow; i +=1)
  {
    string [0] = dgv1.Rows[i].Cells["Total1"].Value.ToString();
    string [1] = dgv1.Rows[i].Cells["Total2"].Value.ToString();
    string [2] = dgv1.Rows[i].Cells["Total3"].Value.ToString();
  }
```

And i am getting error, no value for "i". I am trying to use it in Print action. I give value in BeginPrint event too.

Comment: "And i am getting error" what's the error again?

Comment: index out of range. must be nonnegative and less than the size of the collection.

Comment: isnt that error clear enough?, check that NumofRows is maybe bigger that the actuall number of rows in your datagrid

Comment: Sure, that's enough. But when i use MessageBox between lines, i can see i value and i can read true values. But i can not use thme as Rows index.

Comment: @user3054228 it does not matter if i has a value, for example if i = 10 and you only have 5 rows it will throw the exception you are getting, so be care in that case, remember that the index row starts at 0, so the first row is dgv.Rows[0] and the max is dgv.Rows[dgv.Rows.Count-1]

Comment: Thanks for your replies. I will be more careful.

Comment: Add the error message to your question, comments aren't the correct place for important information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your code is correct but it seems there are some error like you did not use correct pocket size for array and 2nd you missed array name while assigning values to array.

following are the example for your help.

```
string[] Array1 = new string[3];   

                for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.Rows.Count; i +=1)
                {
                    Array1 [0] = dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value.ToString();
                    Array1 [1] = dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[1].Value.ToString();
                    Array1 [2] = dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[2].Value.ToString();
                }
```

Answer (score -1):

i think you want something more like this:

```
List<string[]> allValues = new List<string[]>();
foreach(var row in dvg1.Rows)
{
    string[] arr = new string[3];  
    arr[0] = row.Cells["Total1"].Value.ToString();
    arr[1] = row.Cells["Total2"].Value.ToString();
    arr[2] = row.Cells["Total3"].Value.ToString();

    allValues.add(arr);
}
```

I'm not sure why I've been downvoted. Aside from your compiler errors, I'm trying to address your issue of overwriting yourself with each iteration through the loop.